# OpenGL ambient light

Tags: opengl

Having constructed a very simple OpenGL program consisting of a centered textured cube with respective vertex/normal values of +/-1.0, I have two questions regarding the behaviour of the fixed-pipe lighting model.

1) Why is my object not fully illuminated when I set the global ambient light to {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}. I would have expected these settings to render the model as if lighting had been disabled (i.e. all surfaces are rendered at full intensity).

2) When I place a diffuse light directly in front of the model at {0.0, 0.0, 2.0} everything appears to render correctly, but if I move the light further back at {0.0, 0.0, 200.0} the model renders as if lighting has been disabled (i.e. all surfaces are rendered at full intensity).

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't post your actual setup code, all I can really do is guess.

1: The ambient light intensity is modulated with the ambient surface color. If you have not set up your material correctly, then this value will *not* be the same as the diffuse surface color. Of course, since you didn't post the code, I can't say if you did it correctly or not.

2: I'd need to see a rendering of what's happening, but this is likely caused by not having any kind of intensity falloff. Effectively, as the light gets farther away, it *appears* brighter, because [the normals are more likely to be closer to facing it than if it is close to the surface](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Illumination/Tut10%20Distant%20Points%20of%20Light.html). A point light becomes a directional light when it is moved away. So you need to use attenuation.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Nicol. With regard to ambient light intensity, could you give me an example of light/material values which would render the cube as if light was disabled; would {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0} for both do the trick?  Would a material value of {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0} render the cube black, irrespective of the ambient light value?

Comment: There are _many_ "material value"s; which one in particular are you referring to?

Comment: Say for instance I have no light sources defined, and set the global ambient light to be {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0} via a glLightModel command. Would an ambient meterial value of {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0} do the trick?